Mlflow log_figure deletes artifact
I am running mlflow with autologging to track an xgboost model. By default, under artifacts it saves the model, requirements, and feature importances. Cool stuff I want to keep.

But, if I try to add figures with the code below, it deletes the artifacts folder and puts just my figures into it. What is the best way to append artifacts to the folder?

mlflow.autolog()
mlflow.set_experiment('Energy Use Forecasting')

def main():
    color_pal = sns.color_palette()
    input_file = Path(r'D:\data\ML\PowerConsumption\AEP_hourly.csv')
    models_path = Path(r'D:\Models\ML') / Path(__file__).stem
    models_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    df = df.set_index('Datetime')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

    data_source = input_file.stem.split('_')[0]
    df = df.rename(columns={data_source + '_MW': 'MW'})
    train, val = train_val_split(df)

    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree',
                                 n_estimators=10000,
                                 early_stopping_rounds=50,
                                 objective='reg:squarederror',
                                 max_depth=max_depth,
                                 learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                  eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)],
                  verbose=100)

    ax = df[['MW']].plot(figsize=(15, 5))
    df['prediction'].plot(ax=ax, style='.')
    plt.legend(['Truth Data', 'Predictions'])
    plt.axvline(val_split_index, color="gray", lw=3, label=f"Val split point")
    ax.set_title('Raw Data and Prediction')

    mlflow.log_figure(fig_trainval_preds, 'trainval_predictions.png')


The issue was with mlflow.log_figure() not being aware of the run_id and creating a new run to log to. Although not shown in some examples of mlflow.autolog() use, it is a requirement to wrap any model fitting and plotting code with:
with mlflow.start_run() as run:

Then, manual logging goes to the same run_id as the automated logging.
